# Why is $L(z)=\phi(z) - z \left(1 - \Phi(z)\right) \ge 0$? Why is it (sorta) linear?

Tags: normal-distribution, loss-functions

In [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285698/how-should-i-inverse-of-the-normal-loss-function-lz-to-be-able-to-implement-th), OP is interested, apparently, in a loss function with the ambiguous name "normal loss function" which is defined as
$$
L(z) =\phi(z) - z \left(1 - \Phi(z)\right).
$$

Based on this quick plot, the function is nonnegative and essentially linear for sufficiently small values $z$.

[image]
It's not obvious to me why this must be non-negative, nor is it obvious why it must be essentially linear for small $z$. Is there an intuitive explanation for this behavior?

Comment: This result is contained in the extensive results reported by Cardinal at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7200/evaluate-definite-interval-of-normal-distribution/7206#7206.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since on the interval $x \in [z, \infty)$ it is clear that $x \ge z,$ use the fact that $\phi^\prime(x) = -x \phi(x)$ to conclude

$$\phi(z) = \int_z^\infty (-\phi^\prime(x))dx = \int_{z}^\infty x \phi(x) dx \ge z \int_z^\infty \phi(x) dx = z(1-\Phi(z)),$$

*QED.*

---

**Concerning the second question,** observe that $$L^\prime(z) = \phi^\prime(z) + z\phi(z) - (1-\Phi(z)) = 1-\Phi(z),$$ yielding $L$ as an integral $$L(z)=\int_{\infty}^z (1-\Phi(x))dx \gt 0,$$ which provides another solution to the first question.  Since $1-\Phi(z) \approx 1$ for $z\ll 0,$ $L$ approaches an asymptote with slope $-1$ as $z\to-\infty.$